# Has anyone gone through relocating the %ProgramFiles% directory, and can comment on the process / pro/con's?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, environment-variables

There are [many questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=programfilesdir) on this SE subsite that ask if it is possible/how.

I have commented on some of them that suggest changing the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir` value, with [Microsoft's take on the idea](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700/en-us), and know that the `%ProgramFiles%`  environment values stored under `HKCU\Environment` and `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Sesssion Manager\Environment`, seem to be there solely for legacy applications / those that continue looking at these potentially misleading variables.

However, I am yet to find anyone who has tried this, that can document the pitfalls, workarounds, etc. Has anyone?

Comment: If you have a 64 bit OS you need to change the setting here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir    You have to copy the files over from the C: drive also.  Internet Explorer usually breaks but the tool at tweaking.com fixes it.   In general it is fine, however it can break some programs especially poorly written ones.

Comment: I have a 32bit version of Windows. I suspect the above registry value would apply to the Microsoft KB, the same as the value I mentioned. I unfortunately know of no-one who uses IE, either. Was looking more for a good rundown of *all* effects, and what workarounds someone/some people may have found for each of them.